# Friendly iframe with AMP

Tags: iframe, amp-html

Is it possible to create a friendly iframe with AMP?

I was looking at *amp-iframe* tag, but it requires src, which makes it to belong to another domain, thus restricting access to a parent document due to cross domain policy.

Is there a way to create a friendly iframe, which won't have such restriction?

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to embed a widget into an AMP page which will display additional interactive content based on the page keywords as well as an ad. On a 'traditional' web page this can be done though friendly iframes. I wonder if there is some workaround for AMP?

Comment: I think [`src`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe#src) is required, as it was specified on the [Amp documentation amp-iframe attributes](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to create friendly iframes, the reason is that AMP pages might be served via an AMP Cache on a different origin. In that case friendly iframes would no longer work.

You can embed iframes from the same origin via `amp-iframe` if you omit the `allow-same-origin` attribute. There's also a new [two-way-messaging between amp-iframes and the AMP doc](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-iframe/amp-iframe.md#two-way-messaging-with-iframes) being implemented. This should be available soon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried amp-iframe without allow-same-origin, and it worked for the amp-iframe itself, but all the iframes within it have been blocked, because of this error: "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame." I've updated the question with what I'm trying to achieve. Do you think it's possible with AMP? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you try using the **sandbox** attribute

```
<amp-iframe width="600"
      title="Google map pin on Googleplex, Mountain View CA"
      height="400"
      layout="responsive"
      sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
      frameborder="0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA&key=AIzaSyCNCZ0Twm_HFRaZ5i-FuPDYs3rLwm4_848">
    </amp-iframe>
```

Comment: By default, an amp-iframe is sandboxed. I used sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups", but it doesn't help, because the page domain and the iframe domain are different.